Double standards, inconsistent lines and unwritten rules when downvoting
So, I got downvoted for my answer here:
Are these colored sets closed under multiplication?
According to a commenter, it wasn't really wrong, but it was a bad answer and my reasoning wasn't clear, yet the accepted answer only offered some reasoning for the first case. They also said that it didn't offer anything different. I argued with them and thought it was a double standard to only downvote me for the same wrongdoing (not elaborate explanations) while letting it slide when it comes from other users. Heck, the accepted answer there was very short and guilty of the same thing and still got accepted?
Then they said that downvotes are supposed to be used for "not useful" answers. You can see the phrase when hovering on the downvote button, but by this logic, a new entry is either useful or not, which would mean that anyone who happens to come across an answer can easily take a position (either upvote or downvote). I see plenty of times when a question receives a decent amount of traffic, there's one or two answers stuck at 0 points despite being either good or bad, which doesn't reflect their quality. If I were to post the same answer, I would have been downvoted to death. So where's the line here? When is the rule of thumb refraining from voting (ignoring the possibility that the reader doesn't understand the reasoning but believes it makes some sort of sense so gives the benefit of doubt)?
There are a lot of subtle, unwritten rules here that I don't understand. I'm also worried that I've developed a bad reputation in this community.
